# ColdFusion Link to Previous Page Clears only that Page Session Variables

Tags: coldfusion

I have a page (form) set up like this:

```
<cfif not structKeyExists(session, "checkout")>
    <cflocation url="ownerInfo.cfm" addToken="false">
</cfif>

<cfif not structKeyExists(session.checkout, "vehicle")>
    <cfset session.checkout.vehicle = {ownership=""}

<cfparam name="form.ownership" default="#session.checkout.vehicle.ownership#">

<cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>

    <cfset errors = []>
    <cfif not arrayLen(errors)>
        <cfset session.checkout.vehicle = {ownership=form.ownership}
        <cflocation url="ownerCheck.cfm" addToken="false">
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can reset this form by having a link on another page that when this page is linked back to it will reset all the session variables to null making the entire page needing to be filled out again.

This is what I have tried but am unsuccessful.

```
<cfif session.checkout.vehicle.ownership != null />
    <cfset session.checkout.vehicle.ownership = null />
</cfif>
```

I cannot use `<cfset StructClear(Session)>` because I do not want all the session variables cleared from the previous pages only want this page to reset.(Not All Pages or All Session Variables). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why on earth are you putting the form values into session?

Look at this to get a better understanding of the Scopes available for CF. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html

Comment: im putting them in session variables so I can prefill out pdf forms with them

Comment: Why would you be putting your form values submitted by a user into session?

Comment: So I can use them on multiple other pages?

Comment: Can you not just pass them along in the request to the pdf builder and pull the values?

Comment: Its like a checkout program...

Comment: there not being saved into a database

Comment: It's been awhile since last doing CF but can you '<cfset StructClear(session.checkout)>' ?

Comment: no that didn't work unfortunately I was hopeful though!

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Element CHECKOUT.VEHICLE.OWNERSHIP is undefined in SESSION.

Comment: even though that's not what is in the param

Comment: If you have '<cfset StructClear(session.checkout)>' at the top of your page and are getting an error stating 'Element CHECKOUT.VEHICLE.OWNERSHIP is undefined in SESSION' then you have code somewhere else perhaps in an include that is executing prior to the cfset structclear.

Comment: <cfset StructClear(session.checkout.vehicle)> Can you do something similar to this so that its only that page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do using structDelete(structure,key)

```
<cfif session.checkout.vehicle.ownership != null />
    <cfset structDelete(session.checkout.vehicle,'ownership ')>
</cfif>
```

Comment: This doesn't work  Invalid CFML construct found on line 5 at column 42.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

!

Comment: Invalid CFML construct found on line 5 at column 42.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

!

Comment: Invalid CFML construct found on line 5 at column 42.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

!

The CFML compiler was processing:

    A cfif tag beginning on line 5, column 2.

Comment: is it deleting the structure or just setting it to null?

Comment: Invalid CFML construct found on line 10 at column 50.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

/&gt;

The CFML compiler was processing:

    A cfif tag beginning on line 10, column 2

Comment: Can u paste the line. You told line number 5th now 10th.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the session scope variables if the `ownership` key already exists in the session scope then you can do:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(session.checkout.vehicle, "ownership")>
    <!--- struct key exists so delete it --->
    <cfset structDelete(session.checkout.vehicle, "ownership")>
</cfif>
```

You can actually just do:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(session.checkout, "vehicle")>
    <!--- try and delete ownership key might not exist --->
    <cfset structDelete(session.checkout.vehicle, "ownership")>
</cfif>
```

As long as the parent scope exists, you can try and delete the `ownership` key without first checking that it exists.

If you want to know if the key did exist then `structDelete` accepts a 3rd boolean parameter so it'll return true if it did exists and false if it didn't.

```
<cfset didExist = structDelete(session.checkout.vehicle, "ownership", true)>
```

An alternative approach to solving your problem would be to reset the form if it's not a form (POST) submission. So you'd do:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>
   <!--- form has been submitted store values in session and redirect... -->
<cfelse>
   <!--- form not submitted so clear the session vars... --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: is there a special place I need to insert this ? or can it just be inserted on the very top?

Comment: this is breaking the first time around

Comment: it wont go further than this page because its making ownership null before it goes to the next page I believe

Comment: maybe its not supposed to delete the structure but just reset the variable to null?

Comment: [Zane Z](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4920863/zane-z) bit hard to advise without seeing your complete code. Null in ColdFusion doesn't really exist (it can but normally best to forget about nulls in CF). So you need to delete the key rather than setting it to null.